# Can't display SVG image

Tags: css, svg, sass

I'm trying to display an SVG; the below code works with inline SVG, but now I have an SVG file with lots of content, so I changed it to this:

```
   background:url("data:image/svg+xml;base64, dot-and-circle.svg")  no-repeat;
```

But it's not working. Can anyone help?

```
 body,html,#map_canvas{height:100%;margin:0;}
 #map_canvas .centerMarker{
 position:absolute;
  /*url of the marker*/
 background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg     xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='30' height='30'><circle cx='15'   cy='15' r='10' /></svg>")  no-repeat;
 /*background:url('dot-and-circle.svg') no-repeat;
 /*center the marker*/
 top:50%;left:50%;
 z-index:1;
 /*fix offset when needed*/
 margin-left:-10px;
 margin-top:-34px;
 /*size of the image*/
 height:16px;
 width:16px;
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: Just do `background:url("dot-and-circle.svg");`?

Comment: Na that doesnt work  tried to inspect it on the browser it says failed to load image

Comment: is `dot-and-circle.svg` the name of the file, and is it in the same directory?

Comment: yes thats correct.

Comment: does the SVG display if you just open the svg file in your browser?

Comment: Yes it does the only problem is when i reference it in the css file dont know why it breaks

Comment: Then there is some other problem, check your console. http://helephant.com/2009/08/12/svg-images-as-css-backgrounds/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why would an image fail to load from CSS when the path is correct, but loads when URL entered directly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26264006/why-would-an-image-fail-to-load-from-css-when-the-path-is-correct-but-loads-whe)